# Get a child count using Bookshelf

Tags: bookshelf.js

I want to have child count for every record in table `A`. How do I query if I have `sql` statement like this

```
SELECT A.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM B WHERE B.a_id = A.id) AS TOT FROM A
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to achieve this using knex QueryBuilder

```
A
    .query(qb => {
        qb.select('(SELECT count(*) FROM B WHERE B.id = A.id) AS count');
    })
    .fetchAll()
    .then(data => {
        // Data retrieval
    })
    .catch(err => {
        // Error management
    })
```